# VBA dynamic 1-based array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to create a dynamic range starting at 1.
I do not want to use "Option 1" because the program also uses 0-based arrays.

I cannot use:

`Dim arValues(1 To LastRow, 1 To LastColumn)`

"compiler error: must be constant "

This also does not work:

```
Dim numbers(1 To 6, 1 To 4) As Variant)
ReDim numbers(3, 2)
```

I can do:

```
Dim numbers() As Variant
ReDim numbers(5, 3)
ReDim numbers(3, 2)
```

But not:

```
Dim numbers(5,3) As Variant      (or Dim numbers(1 To 6, 1 To 4) As Variant)
ReDim numbers(3, 2)
```

That does not make sense!

Any ideas?

Sorry, somehow the '''code''' thing does not work

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/vba/topic/3064/arrays)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way:-

```
Dim numbers() As Variant
ReDim numbers(1 To 6, 1 To 4)
```

In case you are thinking of making the array dynamic, note that only the last vector can be modified after the first `ReDim`.